# Alloy 1.8 Update throwing errors with ListView Binding Transforms

Tags: appcelerator

After upgrading to latest Alloy1.8 update, I have started getting Script Errors for my Listview Transform functions.

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 17;
[ERROR] :      line = 4;
[ERROR] :      message = "Can't find variable: PartyName";
[ERROR] :      stack = "anonymous\ntemplate@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/underscore.js:1267:28\n__alloyId721@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/controllers/appointments/inspectionProposal.js:23:37\ntrigger@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/backbone.js:163:23\nreset@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/backbone.js:746:35\nsuccess@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/backbone.js:759:44\nSync@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/sync/sql.js:180:51\nsync@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy.js:108:28\nfetch@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/backbone.js:763:42\nloadInspectionDetails@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/controllers/appointments/inspectionProposal.js:58:43\nController@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/controllers/appointments/inspectionProposal.js:377:26\ncreateController@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy.js:232:54\nController@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/controllers/appointments/appointmentContainer.js:716:56\ncreateController@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy.js:232:54\nopenNewPage@file:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/common/common.js:759:41\nfile:///Users/neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61D305E-4B60-441E-9098-1755F6CFDB09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/33D5C98E-FC76-4845-96B0-CE4BB43F72A3/Residential.app/alloy/controllers/dashboard/dashboardAppointments.js:615:35";
[ERROR] :  }
```

Here is my transform function which does return `transform.PartyName`

```
function addLastInspectedDate(model) {
        var transform = model.toJSON();
        var appointmentDetailsCollection = Alloy.createCollection(modelConfiguration.appointmentList);
        appointmentDetailsCollection.fetch({
            query: {
                statement: query.getAppointmentListById,
                params: [ transform.AppointmentId ]
            }
        });
        appointmentDetailsCollection.each(function(eachRecord) {
            var firstName = eachRecord.get("FirstName");
            var lastName = eachRecord.get("LastName");
            var partyName = "";
            partyName += null != firstName ? firstName : "";
            partyName += "" == partyName ? null != lastName ? lastName : "" : " " + lastName;
            Ti.API.info("partyName:" + partyName);
            transform.PartyName = partyName;
            transform.StreetName = eachRecord.get("StreetName");
            var city = eachRecord.get("City");
            var stateCode = eachRecord.get("StateCode");
            var postalCode = eachRecord.get("PostalCode");
            var addressLine2 = "";
            addressLine2 += null != city ? city : "";
            addressLine2 += "" == addressLine2 ? (null != stateCode ? stateCode : "") + " " + (null != postalCode ? postalCode : "") : "," + (null != stateCode ? stateCode : "") + " " + (null != postalCode ? postalCode : "");
            Ti.API.info("addressLine2:" + addressLine2);
            transform.AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
            transform.DateLastInspected = transform.DateInspected;
            transform.AppointmentId = transform.AppointmentId;
        });
        return transform;
    }
```

ListView Bindings:

```
<ItemTemplate name="selectedInspectionProposal" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" backgroundColor="#119050">
                        <View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.FILL" top="0" bottom="1" backgroundColor="#fff">
                        <View class="selectedInspectionData vgroup" id="inspectionDataContainerId"  top="10">
                            <Label class="selectedGenInfo" bindId="partyName" id="partyNameId"></Label>
                            <Label class="selectedGenInfo" bindId="addressLineOne" id="addressLine1Id"></Label>
                            <Label class="selectedGenInfo" bindId="addressLineTwo" id="addressLine2Id" bottom="15"></Label>
                            <Label class="selectedGenInfo" bindId="inspectedDate" id="inspectedDateId" bottom="10"></Label>
                        </View>
                        </View>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </Templates>
                <ListSection id="section" dataCollection="Inspection" dataTransform="addLastInspectedDate">
                    <ListItem template="inspectionProposal" partyName:text="{PartyName}" addressLineOne:text="{StreetName}" addressLineTwo:text="{AddressLine2}"  inspectedDate:text="{DateLastInspected}" appointmentId:text="{AppointmentId}"  selectedBackgroundColor="#119050"></ListItem>
                </ListSection>
```

inspectionProposal.js generated with Alloy 1.8.2

```
function __alloyId726(e) {
    if (e && e.fromAdapter) return;
    var opts = __alloyId726.opts || {};
    var models = __alloyId725.models;
    var len = models.length;
    var __alloyId721 = [];
    for (var i = 0; len > i; i++) {
        var __alloyId722 = models[i];
        __alloyId722.__transform = addLastInspectedDate(__alloyId722);
        var __alloyId724 = {
            template: "inspectionProposal",
            partyName: {
                text: _.template("{PartyName}", __alloyId722.__transform, {
                    interpolate: /\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g
                })
            },
            addressLineOne: {
                text: _.template("{StreetName}", __alloyId722.__transform, {
                    interpolate: /\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g
                })
            },
            addressLineTwo: {
                text: _.template("{AddressLine2}", __alloyId722.__transform, {
                    interpolate: /\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g
                })
            },
            inspectedDate: {
                text: _.template("{DateLastInspected}", __alloyId722.__transform, {
                    interpolate: /\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g
                })
            },
            appointmentId: {
                text: _.template("{AppointmentId}", __alloyId722.__transform, {
                    interpolate: /\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g
                })
            },
            properties: {
                selectedBackgroundColor: "#119050"
            }
        };
        __alloyId721.push(__alloyId724);
    }
    opts.animation ? $.__views.section.setItems(__alloyId721, opts.animation) : $.__views.section.setItems(__alloyId721);
}
```

inspectionProposal.js generated with Alloy 1.7.6

```
function __alloyId742(e) {
        if (e && e.fromAdapter) return;
        var opts = __alloyId742.opts || {};
        var models = __alloyId741.models;
        var len = models.length;
        var __alloyId737 = [];
        for (var i = 0; len > i; i++) {
            var __alloyId738 = models[i];
            __alloyId738.__transform = addLastInspectedDate(__alloyId738);
            var __alloyId740 = {
                template: "inspectionProposal",
                partyName: {
                    text: "undefined" != typeof __alloyId738.__transform["PartyName"] ? __alloyId738.__transform["PartyName"] : __alloyId738.get("PartyName")
                },
                addressLineOne: {
                    text: "undefined" != typeof __alloyId738.__transform["StreetName"] ? __alloyId738.__transform["StreetName"] : __alloyId738.get("StreetName")
                },
                addressLineTwo: {
                    text: "undefined" != typeof __alloyId738.__transform["AddressLine2"] ? __alloyId738.__transform["AddressLine2"] : __alloyId738.get("AddressLine2")
                },
                inspectedDate: {
                    text: "undefined" != typeof __alloyId738.__transform["DateLastInspected"] ? __alloyId738.__transform["DateLastInspected"] : __alloyId738.get("DateLastInspected")
                },
                appointmentId: {
                    text: "undefined" != typeof __alloyId738.__transform["AppointmentId"] ? __alloyId738.__transform["AppointmentId"] : __alloyId738.get("AppointmentId")
                },
                properties: {
                    selectedBackgroundColor: "#119050"
                }
            };
            __alloyId737.push(__alloyId740);
        }
        opts.animation ? $.__views.section.setItems(__alloyId737, opts.animation) : $.__views.section.setItems(__alloyId737);
    }
```

Comment: This might be https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1474 but the error is not what I'd expect it to be in that case. Could you share the compiled code in `Resources/alloy/controllers/appointments/inspectionProposal.js` both with Alloy 1.8.2 and 1.7.x?

Comment: Hi Fokke, adding generated code on both versions to question description.

Comment: Thanks. Could you log in `addLastInspectedDate()` just before the return and check if all items have a `partyName` property?